# Django: Add user to group via Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I add users to a group in Django admin interface of "Change Group"?

I have seen dirty hacks to get this working for older django version.

How to solve this with Django 1.10?

Emphasize: I want this on the page "Change Group", not on "Change User".

I would like to have this in django-admin-style: No coding, just doing some configuration. Maybe like this:

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    show_reverse_many_to_many = ('user',)
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to write *some* code. Note that the Django admin site is normal Django views and forms!

First create a ModelForm:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple    
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


User = get_user_model()


# Create ModelForm based on the Group model.
class GroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude = []

    # Add the users field.
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
         queryset=User.objects.all(), 
         required=False,
         # Use the pretty 'filter_horizontal widget'.
         widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('users', False)
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do the normal form initialisation.
        super(GroupAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # If it is an existing group (saved objects have a pk).
        if self.instance.pk:
            # Populate the users field with the current Group users.
            self.fields['users'].initial = self.instance.user_set.all()

    def save_m2m(self):
        # Add the users to the Group.
        self.instance.user_set.set(self.cleaned_data['users'])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Default save
        instance = super(GroupAdminForm, self).save()
        # Save many-to-many data
        self.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

We added a custom Group ModelForm. The second step is to unregister the original Group admin and register a new Group admin that displays our ModelForm:

```
# Unregister the original Group admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)

# Create a new Group admin.
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Use our custom form.
    form = GroupAdminForm
    # Filter permissions horizontal as well.
    filter_horizontal = ['permissions']

# Register the new Group ModelAdmin.
admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

[image: Screenshot Django custom form and filter_horizontal in Group admin]

Comment: Works great. Thank you.

Comment: Missing import:  from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

Comment: While trying this I found it does not work, and it should not according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method - you should call parent save with commit=True, then save the many-to-many data, in a save_m2m method.

Comment: I didn't test it, but believe, you and the official documentation are right. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I created a git repository, with 100% test coverage, travis support, and pypi installable: https://github.com/microdisseny/django-groupadmin-users

Comment: Slick solution, thanks! For anyone coming to use this solution, grab the latest from pip/github (Initially I had copied the code above, but Django 2.1 complained about directly accessing user_set in save_m2m).

Comment: @allcaps consider that you have 100K users. This solution will display all of them as options. As you guess, it will make page performance extremely slow or crash in higher numbers. How would you achieve not displaying them initially and display only if filter exists?

Comment: Since we already override the form, it is pretty easy. We define the field `users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`, just filter that queryset.

Comment: You can also just use some other widget that doesn't load all the users. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L200

Comment: @allcaps but I don't want to filter users queryset, all users must be a valid option.

Comment: Yes, change `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget into `ManyToManyRawIdWidget`.

Comment: not working :(. It says - 'str' object has no attribute 'model'

Comment: You might get the widget with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields . If not, search on how to use the ManyToManyRawIdWidget or ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204111/discussion-between-elgin-cahangirov-and-allcaps).

Comment: I managed to use `ManyToManyRawIdWidget` properly, but that is not what I want. Anyway, thanks for support.

Comment: in example above, to fix performance issue, just change widget type from `widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('users', False)` to 
`widget=AutocompleteSelectMultiple(Group.user_set.field, admin.site)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to write code to achieve what you want, since django admin provides the change form, for the model that has the M2M field in it, namely `User`, since m2m to `Group` is inside that model.

So basically, doing it completely in django admin and nice, you probably need to override several functions and provide your own implementation.

```
class GroupForm(forms.Form):
    blah
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label=_('Users'), required=False, queryset=User.objects.all(),
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(is_stacked=True, verbose_name=_('Users')),help_text=mark_safe("Help text")
    )

class GroupAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    form = GroupForm
    # you can here define fieldsets to render your form more beautifully

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        current_group = form.instance
        # ....
        # Update relations between users and the group here, both are
        # accessible with the form instance

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        # If you want to render the form with initial data for the user
        # you may optionally override this method as well.
        initial = super(GroupAdmin, self).get_changeform_initial_data(request)
        initial.update({'users': ...})
        return initial
```

This is the most django-ic way I find to implement what you want! Hope it helps or give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

On Change group page  you have to override the change group form and add a multiple selectbox with users