# Django: How to add users from group view in django admin?

Tags: django

How can i add users to a group using django admin just like adding permission ?
A found an answer for older version of django 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39648244/11616789

How can i implement it in django 2 and above

Comment: Could you please share the progress you have made in using the method specified in the answer linked by you?

Comment: I don't understand where should i put the code

Comment: admin module related code usually goes into a file called admin.py inside the app you are creating the admin module for.

Comment: yes and here is my problem
i want to edit group form which is by default in django admin app, i can't find admin.py for that one

Comment: Is it different from the widget that automatically shows up by default when we try to create the admin interface for a model with many to many relationship?